# How to get another root for a given database

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a train root project in php :

let I have three trains which goes to stations as follow :

```
Train A => 1->2->3
Train B => 2->3->4
Train C => 2->4->5
```

If I want to go go to `Station 1 to 5`, then I know that I have to change two trains first I have to travel by `A` and then I have to travel by `C`. But I am not getting any solution that How can I implement using `php mysql`

My database structure is as follow :

Table 1 :

Trains : `Fields : ID, name`

Table 2 :

Routes : `Fields : ID, name`

Table 3 :

Finale : `Fields : ID, trainid, stopid, priority`

If the complete journey is done by one train then I am using the following query :

```
$dest = $_POST['desstaion'];
    $st = $_POST['ststaion'];
    $query = mysql_query("select * from(select busid,position from route where stopid='$st') as a join (select busid,position from route where stopid='$dest') as b on a.busid = b.busid");
    $numResults = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

If I need to change any train then How can I detect this using mysql ?

Comment: Explain whether you need shortest path(minimum station) or minimum train changes.

Comment: This is not a good task for mysql - real solutions for non-trivial cases might have variable numbers of trains/changes and multiple paths of the same "length" - you are working on some graph optimization probably, use proper tools.

Answer (score 0):

This is some of the worst problems to solve with mysql. If it's only for educational approaches it's possible if you can assume, that the shortest path from 1->3 goes over 2. But that's not the case in a real use-case, and is still quite hard.
You should consider using other tools!

If you need to use MySQL you can try looking at this -> http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=766 but as said, it will be difficult!